# Hadoop Library is imported but cannot set the "get" method in FyleSystem

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I'm trying to setting up a call to HDFS to get a file from it using FileSystem to do so:
`FileSystem fs = new FileSystem.get(new URI.create(uri), conf);`

But I getting this two errors even so I called all the libraries

```
    Error:(46, 39) java: cannot find symbol
    symbol:   class get
    location: class org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem

    Error:(46, 47) java: cannot find symbol
    symbol:   method create(java.lang.String)
    location: class org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI
```

This is for hadoop 2.7.7 version. I already tried imported the hole library 
`org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;`
but still the method `get` and `create` is not there when I'm trying to use them in the line as follow:
`FileSystem fs = new FileSystem.get(URI.create(usi), conf)`

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;   

public class Test { 
  public static void main(String []args) {

    String uri = "hdfs://localhost:9000/data.json";
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    //cannot find symbol get
    //Cannot find symbol create
    FileSystem fs = new FileSystem.get(new URI.create(uri), conf);

    InputStream in = null;

    try {
        in = fs.open(new Path(uri));
        IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeStream(in);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my POM.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.boeing.bedl</groupId>
<artifactId>IngestionData</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem is that you have imported `import org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI;` instead of `java.net.URI`

That's why you get an error for missing **.create** method which is part of java.net.URI and you get an error on **.get** method because you pass the wrong type of URI.

(I would guess some auto import of the IDE? :) )

Comment: Yes, you where right, I solve part of the problem changing library `java.net.URI` but the` get () `method still get me an error. Was the auto import from the IDE, most of the time it get it right.

Comment: Just for the get() method part, the error for the .create was solve it importing the right library

Comment: Check my answer please, you have to remove both `new` from `FileSystem fs = new FileSystem.get(new URI.create(uri), conf);`

Answer (score 0):

You have two problem. Based on @Veselin Davidov's answer, you have to change import to `java.net.URI`:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI;
```

to

```
import java.net.URI;
```

The second, you use both of a new operator and a static factory method:

```
FileSystem fs = new FileSystem.get(new URI.create(uri), conf);
```

so you have to use the factory instead:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
```

Comment: Changing the libraries `import org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI;
` for `import java.net.URI;` solve the `.create` part, but still .get() is giving me the same error message

Comment: Sorry I took a mistake, @EEstereo please see my edited solution.

Comment: I change the way you mention, but still is the same error I'm thinking this must be related with the library, like in the first case.

Comment: Without `new`, you should get different compile errors.

Comment: I didn't see that, you got it